# Scale Socket.io vertically AND horizontally - what is the "right" way to go?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, rabbitmq, scalability

I want to scale my Node.js Socket application **vertically** and **horizontally** and I haven´t found a sophisticated solution yet.

My application has two use-cases:

1. Broadcast messages from one user to all others
2. Push messages from one user to a subset of users

---

On one hand, I´ve read that I need Redis for **both** cases together with [socket.io-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis)

On the other hand, I´ve watched [this video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Subscribe/Glenn-Block-Explains-SocketIO-Scale-Out-on-Service-Bus) and read this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122005/redis-vs-service-bus-for-pub-sub-scenario) where it says that **Redis** isn´t reliable and it´s **not guaranteed that the published messages will arrive**, so you should **only use it for clustering/vertical scaling**

Microsoft Azures solution to use **ServiceBus** is out of question, because I don´t want to use Azure.

Instead of Redis, the guy recommends using **[RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)** for horizontal scaling.

For the vertical scaling there is also **[socket.io-clusterhub](https://github.com/Mklueh/socket.io-clusterhub)**, an IPC for node processes, but it seems to work only on **Socket.io <= v0.9.0**

Then there is [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21628416/2324388), who has implemented his own method to pass messages to other nodes via HTTP requests, which makes somehow sense. But why HTTP requests if you could also establish direct socket connections between servers, push the message to all servers simultaneously and overcome the delay of going from one server to another?

---

As a conclusion I thought maybe I could go with **Redis** on EACH server, just for the exchange of messages when clustering my application on multiple processes, together with **RabbitMQ** as a **S2S** communication solution.

**But it seems a bit like an overkill to have one Redis per Server and another central RabbitMQ.**

Is there any known shorter/better solution to scale Socket.io reliably in both directions?

---

EDIT:
I´ve tried using a single Redis Server for multiple Node.js Servers, where each of them uses Clustering via [sticky-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sticky-session) over all cores. While the Clustering at its own works like a charm with redis, there seems to be a problem when using multiple servers. **Messages won´t arrive at the other nodes**.

Comment: RabbitMQ can cover both of your use cases (broadcast and multicast), and you can create a cluster of rabbitmq nodes to which you can later add/remove nodes as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say Kafka is a good fit for the horizontal scaling. It is a fairly sophisticated way of distributing a huge amount of events across servers (which at the end is what you want). This is a good read about it: https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/running-kafka-scale

Regarding the vertical scale, instead of socket.io-clusterhub I would use something called PM2 (https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) which allows you to resize the scale of the apps in every computer dynamically as well as controlling the logs and reporting to keymetrics.io (if you are using it).

If you need any snippets ask me and I will edit the answer but in the PM2 github there are quite few.

Comment: Hey can you add some snippets. I am also looking in the same direction as the question.